# Copy Pasting table to variable range based on condition and fixed offset

Tags: excel, vba

The macro is suppose to copy a fixed table 1 ("E19:Q34") and paste it to a range which is 15 column offset of cell E19 i.e. "T19" and would be called 'Table 2'. the next time the macro runs it should be able to detect the table and further move ahead 15 columns to "AI19" and so on..

```
Sub Macro()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng, rng1, rng2 As Range, ws As Worksheet, 

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("E19")
Set rng1 = Rng.Offset(0, 15)
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("E19:Q34") 'fixed base range



'Copy the range with text and paste it after finding the right location

    rng2.copy

    rng1.Select

        For Each rng1 In rng1.Cells

            If rng1.Value = "" Then

                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                ws.Paste
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Exit For

            Else

                Range(rng1).Address = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15) 'attempting to change the reference of rng1 

               ' MsgBox rng1
            End If

        Next rng1
End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro()

    Const COL_OFFSET As Long = 15
    Dim rng, ws As Worksheet, cols As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set rng = ws.Range("E19:Q34")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    rng.Copy
    cols = COL_OFFSET

    'find the next empty slot
    Do While Application.CountA(rng.Offset(0, cols)) > 0
        cols = cols + COL_OFFSET
    Loop

    With rng.Offset(0, cols)
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    End With

End Sub
```